# Display List Architecture in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm asked about Display List architecture in Flex at an interview. Later I searched about it but no use. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question is not clear. What is 'Display List'? Did you mean list based component's architecture, or you mean core architecture of every viewable component and container?

Comment: @user1113426 I think the question is absolutely clear. There is only one display list to talk about when it comes to Flash.

Comment: @AscensionSystems In the question, it is mentioned about Flex , not Flash. If flash , I agree with you, that there is no ambiguity.

Comment: imho the question is about flex4/spark skins

Comment: Its either the inheritance hierarchy for a Flex Component or Application or Display List architecture of Flash. Alternatively it can also be about the flex component life cycle.. If the question is about display list, there is just 1 diplay list as @AscensionSystems said.

Comment: i used this question to check if candidates knew how flex4 skin system is really working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Display List is like a tree. Imagine the Stage object as the base of the tree. Think of MovieClips and Sprites that are added to the stage as branches and leaves coming off of the tree. The Display List also serves as the core for the event system in AVM2. Objects that are attached to the DisplayList (that is, they themselves or their parent, parents parent etc end up connecting to the Stage) can "bubble" events through the Display List.

Anyway that's my short little way of explaining it but you can get much more detailed information from these links:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/colin-moocks-lost-actionscript-weekend/the-display-list/

Comment: The provided links give complete explanation of display list. Thank you :)

Comment: Nice!. That article should fill most, if not all, of the gaps :)

Comment: If you're learning flash/flex then you definitely want to also check out http://gotoandlearn.com/.

Answer (score 1):

seems like the question should really sound as follows:
*when you write [`<s:Application>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html#propertySummary) (or any other [`SkinnableContainer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableContainer.html) / [`UIComponent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html)) in your mxml code -- what is the structure of the resulting display list?*

so you should do something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" applicationComplete="onAppComplete();">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        import flash.display.DisplayObject;
        import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.core.UIComponent;
        import spark.components.SkinnableContainer;
        private function onAppComplete(e:* = null):void {
            trace(parseList(stage));
            //Alert.show(parseList(stage));
        }

        private function parseList(uic:DisplayObjectContainer, prefix:String = '>'):String{
            prefix = prefix || '>';
            var retStr:String = '';
            for (var i:int = 0; i < uic.numChildren; i++ ) {
                retStr += prefix + uic.getChildAt(i).name + '\n';
                if (uic.getChildAt(i) is DisplayObjectContainer) {
                    retStr += parseList(uic.getChildAt(i) as DisplayObjectContainer, prefix + '>');
                }
            }
            return retStr; 
        }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:SkinnableContainer>
        <s:Panel>
            <mx:UIComponent>

            </mx:UIComponent>
        </s:Panel>
    </s:SkinnableContainer>
</s:Application>
```

(or maybe more complex) and study the output
the code above outputs

```
>root1
>>NewFile1
>>>ApplicationSkin3
>>>>Group4
>>>>>Group5
>>>>>>SkinnableContainer6
>>>>>>>SkinnableContainerSkin7
>>>>>>>>Group8
>>>>>>>>>Panel9
>>>>>>>>>>PanelSkin10
>>>>>>>>>>>RectangularDropShadow11
>>>>>>>>>>>Group12
>>>>>>>>>>>>Group13
>>>>>>>>>>>>instance36
>>>>>>>>>>>>Group14
>>>>>>>>>>>>>Group15
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Label16
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>instance33
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>instance37
>>>>>>>>>>>>>Group17
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>UIComponent18
```